# How do I move the blog title below the image on Squarespace?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm trying to move the title below the image.

This is my [site](http://www.thisisartdirection.com)

Here's an [example](http://www.thisiscollate.com) of what I'm looking to achieve.

I know I could just wrap the first line of post with h1 tags but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

you can just move the `header Section` below the `body entry-content` but if you just want to do it with CSS(its not a very good idea) but it can be done as:

**Only change these style**

```
.collection-type-blog article header
{
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 37px;
}

.collection-type-blog article .post 
{
     top: -63px;
     position: relative;
}

.collection-type-blog article .article-meta 
{
     top: 63px;
     position: relative;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can just swap header and body entry-content div classes. You can do it in another way by swapping css properties for both also instead of changing total content.